# ～とく・ておく to emphasize a negative thing?

Tags: grammar, idioms

I know ておく・とく as meaning "in preparation for something". But today I came across the following two sentences:

> あれだけみっともない辞め方をしといて、まだ政府にモノが言えるのは、民主党はいまだ鳩山の懐をあてにして金を貰っているのでしょうか。 (from Oshiete Goo)
>
> AKB48は国民を騙す売り方をしといて国民的と呼ばないでほしい。 (from Yahoo answers)

It seems to me that in these two sentences, （方を）しといて is meant to emphasize a bad thing (quitting / follow deceiving sales pattern), but I'm not sure. Is this a fixed pattern of speech?

Answer (score -1):

Let's think of it as it before handy definitions.

おく means to put something somewhere and often leave it in a certain state, thus, しておく means to do something and leave it as it is. (With implication that it's done for a certain purpose, it makes the meaning of "in preparation".)

In this example, it enhances the effect of contrast together with まだ by expressing how he does it while the fact that he resigned like that precedes and remains unchanged.